# Uploading files POST urls raise 404 when deploy

Tags: django, apache, cpanel

I'm deploying a django app on a host with apache and cPanel. I think I did all the steps that django needs to deploy. Everything works fine except dome **admin** posts urls.
When I'm sending a form via post **from the admin site**, and one of its fields is a File that will be uploaded to a directory, the server responses me 404. Some info:
Python 3.5, Django 1.11.9
Error: 404 Not Found
When: sending any post form containing a Choose File field, even if the file isn't mandatory.
The forms without files in their fields work fine. In production everything works perfect.
I have a symlink in the public_html folder to my media and static folders.
**This error only shows in the admin page. I can upload file from the site without any problem**
This is my code:
**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
prefix_default_language=False)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

This is my first time hosting a website, so, sorry if I'm asking a dummy question, but I couldn't find any solution, even here. Also, sorry for my English. Thanks for the future answers

**EDIT**
My non-admin forms work perfect. The problem is in the admin page. I edited my old question with the changes in bold

Comment: If you attach your project's base `urls.py` file, I may provide a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328969/cannot-upload-media-files-on-cpanel-using-django See the solution in this stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

It can be web server problem. Check your cPanel settings
May be something wrong with your wsgi file location 
Check up [some tutorial](https://libyanspider.com/knowledge/install-run-python-django-using-cpanel/) for more info.

Comment: I followed a lot of tutorials, I don't think is server problem

Answer (score 0):

In case you are serving media files using django's static file server, the `urlpatterns` variable in your project's base `urls.py` file should be assigned in a specific order so that the `i18n_patterns(...)` assignment places before the `static(...)` url.

you should do it like so:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=False)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```