# Cannot upload media files on CPanel (using django)

Tags: python, django, cpanel, namecheap

I am not able to upload my media files on Cpanel. Initially I was able to upload files but now it shows Error 404 URL Not Found.

There is nothing wrong with my code or my url as it works fine on localhost.

I have checked for permissions of directory in my CPanel File Manager (its 0755).

I have specified  **+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)** in my urls.py file.

My settings.py is:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/my/path/public_html/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I am using Django=2.1 and CPanel Shared Hosting

I know its recommended to have a web server to store and serve media files in Production Environment but it would be helpful if I get a solution of this error.

Answer (score 7):

add this code to **passenger_wsgi.py** file and change project_name at line 4:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
SCRIPT_NAME = os.getcwd()
class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib.parse import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME
        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

for more: go to [here](https://smartlazycoding.com/django-tutorial/deploy-a-django-website-to-a2-hosting)

Comment: Thank you, this worked, can you also tell me what the issue really was?

Comment: I also want to know that. I've been having this error since some time this year

Comment: @Ombori  SCRIPT_NAME in the passenger_wsgy.py file is set to a relative path instead of the root of the application

Answer (score 1):

Edit your **settings.py** and add the following lines at the end:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/public_html/static'
```

Replace username with your cPanel username. The STATIC_ROOT basically points to a folder named static inside your domain root directory. You will use public_html only if you are working on your **main domain**.

Now, if you are working on a **subdomain**, you will use the folder name instead of *public_html* as shown.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/test.mydomain.com/static'
```

Now open the terminal in cpanel, activate the virtual environment and execute the following command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

The static files should be copied to the target folder.
**Add:**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Go to setup python app in cPanel and restart the python app.
You can see more here [link](https://pythonfusion.com/media-files-and-static-files-django-shared-hosting/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding slash at the end of your path

MEDIA_ROOT = '/my/path/public_html/media/'